# Which permission should be submit for for approval from facebook to getting user's friend list

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I am developing an app and there is login using `Facebook account's credential`. The application need user's friend list as I have custom selector to invite friends. Then I read documentation of Facebook they clearly says that you have to submit your app for review process, so which permission should be submit for approval either `user_friends` or `read_friendlists`(I saw in submission form).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#invite_to_app**

You can´t get all friends anymore with `/me/friends`, but if your App is a game on Facebook Canvas, you can use [`/me/invitable_friends`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/invitable_friends).

Btw, you don´t need extra approval for `user_friends`, and `read_friendlists` is only for getting the lists - without any friends. It is definitely not what you want. And you only need to submit your App for review if you want to request additional permissions or if you want your game to show up in the App Center on Facebook.

Comment: But my app is not a game it's a video app

Comment: in that case you can´t get all friends, only those who authorized your app too (with /me/friends).